# Detect with Left Join duplicates entries and return the first value, also return sum of duplicates entries

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mysql-workbench

¡Hi!, i have a case with two tables than can have a lot of matches entries and the time of fetching increases a lot.

This tables can be

Table A: Employees

```
-------------------------
| Name   | ID | Account |
-------------------------
| Nicole | 01 | 12345   |
| Alexis | 02 | 67890   |
-------------------------
```

And Table B: BankAccounts

```
--------------------------
| Name   | ID  | Account |
--------------------------
| Nicole | 01  | 12345   |
| Nicole | 01  | 67890   | //duplicates Accounts
| Alexis | 02  | 67890   | //duplicates Accounts
--------------------------
```

And i want to do this with a Left Join in a Table that can have more of 450,000 different entries

Result Table C

```
Column_A = ¿Exists the account number in other register?
Column_B = if(NumberOfMatches > 1) //this means that the account be found 
in other user AND i want to get the first value of all posibles number of matches

                         |Account exists in other user|Match in User..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name   | ID  | Account | Column_A | NumberOfMatches | Column_B    | BadID |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|
| Nicole | 01  | 12345   | No       |       1         | Nicole (OK) | null  |
| Alexis | 02  | 67890   | Yes      |       2         | Nicole (BAD)|   01  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks and regards!

Note: sorry for my english, im learning :p

Comment: No need (ever) to apologize for your english. Are you using MySQL-8.0 or MariaDB-10.2 or newer?

Comment: Thks man! im currently using MySQL-8.0 @danblack

Comment: What output do you want if the amount of Account duplicates is 3 or more?

Comment: @Akina the first value of all matches

Comment: *the first value of all matches* This is for `Column_B`. But what about column `Name` - all except first? like in [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/260108/150107)?

Comment: @Akina column mmh the firsr column name? I want that the column only returns values from Table A (Employees) and the column b show the name result from first value of query, or im not understanding ur question?

Comment: Simply open the fiddle in my answer and look. Does its output is safe for you?

Comment: @Akina im looking it! And looks nice, im will test that query, just one question, what means in the left join query when u using “id > id” or “id <“ because in my case dont care if the id is the number is bigger or minor

Comment: ON clause contains an expression which returns boolean (or a value which may be converted to boolean). Unequiation is not worth then equiation or any another expression - any expression, function and even subquery is safe in ON clause if their results may be treated as boolean.

Comment: What is the algorithm for picking "first"?  Tables are unordered.  `SELECTs` can have `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN t1.Name
            ELSE t2.Name
            END Name,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN t1.ID
            ELSE t2.ID
            END ID,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN t1.Account
            ELSE t2.Account
            END Account,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Yes'
            END Column_A,
       ( SELECT COUNT(t4.Account)
         FROM BankAccounts t4
         WHERE t1.Account = t4.Account ) NumberOfMatches,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN CONCAT(t1.Name, ' (OK)')
            ELSE CONCAT(t1.Name, ' (BAD)')
            END Column_B,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE t1.ID
            END BadID
FROM BankAccounts t1
LEFT JOIN BankAccounts t2 ON t1.Account = t2.Account
                         AND t1.ID < t2.ID
LEFT JOIN BankAccounts t3 ON t1.Account = t3.Account
                         AND t1.ID > t3.ID
WHERE t3.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY Account, ID;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77443aa572e6bbf8cc729fe592ccb660)

Comment: Nice tool! I didn't know about his existence!

Well, i've designed one case in that tool (Tables), as you can see, we can have one table in where we have employees with "correct" accounts (Table Employees) and other table than can contains same information BUT in accounts bank we can find variations (This problem come from business and i cant change it), so, my idea was that using left join query with 'On a.Account Like concat('%', b.Account, '%') try to identify the cases in the table than you designed

[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1dbeb8d31f3410cc5646de72e0d61b0)

Comment: I forgot change type 'INT' for 'Double'

Comment: @BryannLuna Edit your fiddle. And check that ALL statements are executed without errors (in your fiddle 5th query, INSERT INTO, gives an error). Put each query in a separate field (error messages are listed only for 1st query in the inputbox) until their debugging, and compact into one field only when they have no errors..

Comment: sorry sorry, here its the correct [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1dbeb8d31f3410cc5646de72e0d61b0)

Comment: In simple words, i should detect than the account bank of Nicole (12345) exists in other user

Comment: @BryannLuna What fields are related in tables? Name - clear, matched. ID - must match? or it is possible that a pair (Name, ID) from one table have no according pair in another table? Account - not matched, and the same name is a random?

Comment: No, the ID will not always match, if the ID dont match, the name will not match even but the account can match

Comment: For example here [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=700c95c8d3e805e7f3a432377d30c4919) the query should returns me that the number account of Nicole has been matched with other person and in the same time should returns me the name of the first value (in the case that should be more than 2,3 or more..)

Comment: @BryannLuna *but the account can match* ??? in your fiddle no matched Account values. *For example here link* Please always check your input, including links availability - it seems you have added excess symbol to the URL.

Comment: yes, the final account can contains between numbers the correct account

Comment: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c86002fc19a131e70d4e98489b1ece61)

Comment: @BryannLuna Please 1) Create source data which contains ALL possible combinations for data relations (correct and incorrect, duplicated and not, ... - I think it will be ~30-40 records) 2) Create a fiddle with this data and check it for errors absence 3) Edit your question, add this data into it 4) Add desired result for this fiddle in table form.

Comment: i will try it! Thanks so much for ur help!